# Convert Eigen::Matrix to vector using std::move on Eigen::Matrix::data()

Tags: c++, eigen, move-semantics

I know these conversion topics have been raised multiple times but I could not find one considering move semantics.

I am wondering if the following is safe:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(n,n);

//fill matrix A

std::vector<double> A_vec;
A_vec.insert(A_vec.end(), std::make_move_iterator(A.data()), std::make_move_iterator(A.data() + A.size()));

//destruct A
```

Comment: Move or not makes no differnece for a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you actually want to do this for a non-trivial scalar (instead of `double`) which has move-semantics, this should be safe -- of course, as long as you don't use `A` afterwards. For `double` it is safe as well, but it makes no difference.

In your case it may actually be better to map the data of a `std::vector` to an `Eigen::Map`, something like this:

```
std::vector<double> A_vec(n*n); // allocate data into A_vec
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A(A_vec.data(), n, n);
// fill matrix A.
// data is immediately stored into A_vec
```